MAUI - Code based views/Layouts not using full width
I am learning Maui and how it lays out its controls.  In the little practice app I have going I extended Grid and was able to add it to an grid to display little vertical areas on my main screen.
However I was looking at adding some color and graphics but I cannot seem to get the Grid itself to take up the full area it has been assigned.

My code for the "wings" looks like this.  Each wing in a grid area that 1 row and 15% of the screen.
public SideLayout(SideStackAlignment side)
{
    _side = side;
    Setup();
}

private void Setup()
{
    RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection(new []
    {
        new RowDefinition(GridLength.Auto),
        new RowDefinition(GridLength.Auto)
    });
    ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection(new[]
    {
        new ColumnDefinition(GridLength.Auto)
    });
    
    Rotation = _side == SideStackAlignment.Left ? 270 : 90;
    HorizontalOptions = _side == SideStackAlignment.Left ? LayoutOptions.Start : LayoutOptions.End;
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
    BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#cccccc");

    _title = new Label
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        TextTransform = TextTransform.Uppercase,
        
        FontFamily = "OpenSansRegular",
        FontSize = 18,
        TextColor = AppColors.TextColor
    };
    this.Add(_title, 0,0);
    
    _detail = new Label
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        TextTransform = TextTransform.Uppercase,
        
        FontFamily = "OpenSansRegular",
        FontSize = 30,
        TextColor = AppColors.TextColor
    };
    this.Add(_detail, 0,1);

}

Any help would be appreciated. I like clarity of adding these custom controls via code instead of XAML due to future features, but cannot figure out why the gray background doesnt takeup the full "wing" area

the Label and its background will only be as large as necessary to fit their contents.  If you need them larger you will have to apply additional criteria

When you use GridLength.Auto it only takes the space that it needs and won't expand itself, if that is what you want you should use
var length = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

here 1 represents the ratio at which it should expand in cases where multiple views have Star as GridLength.
